# Button_to in email not posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing, link-to

**SEE UPDATE for evolution of this question**

On my website, each user has a dashboard where s/he can click a link to either ACCEPT or DECLINE an request. Depending on what is clicked, the Request record is then PATCHed with the relevant status. To make it easier for users, I'm trying to embed this dashboard in an email to them so that they never have to go to the website directly; think of an email that looks like this:

*Hi there,*

*You have the following requests, click ACCEPT/DECLINE next to the request to do so*

- *Request A: ACCEPT, DECLINE*
- *Request B: ACCEPT, DECLINE*

....

The only way to make this work thus far has been to have a parallel set of GET routes for the links used in email, versus the PATCH routes for the links used in the actual website dashboard.

Wondering if there's a better way of doing this?

Routes

```
patch 'inventories/:id/accept', to: 'inventories#accept', as: 'lender_accept'
patch 'inventories/:id/decline', to: 'inventories#decline', as: 'lender_decline'
get 'inventories/:id/accept_email', to: 'inventories#accept', as: 'lender_accept_email'
get 'inventories/:id/decline_email', to: 'inventories#decline', as: 'lender_decline_email'
```

Link in email

```
<%= "#{link_to 'ACCEPT', lender_accept_email_url(borrow), method: :patch} or #{link_to 'DECLINE', lender_decline_email_url(borrow)}" %>
```

Link on website dashboard

```
<%= "#{link_to 'ACCEPT', lender_accept_path(borrow), method: :patch} or #{link_to 'DECLINE', lender_decline_path(borrow), method: :patch}" %>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Ok tried the `button_to` to generate a form to POST to avoid using GET to do POST as was the "patchy" solution above, still not working...

**Routes:**

```
post 'inventories/:id/accept', to: 'inventories#accept', as: 'lender_accept'
post 'inventories/:id/decline', to: 'inventories#decline', as: 'lender_decline'
```

**Mailer view:**

```
<%="#{button_to 'YES', lender_accept_url(borrow), method: :post, id: "accept #{borrow.id}", style: "background-color:green; color: white; width: 40px; display: inline"} %>
<%="#{button_to 'NO', lender_decline_url(borrow), method: :post, id: "decline #{borrow.id}", style: "background-color:gray; width: 40px; display: inline"}" %>
```

I did an inspect element on the email as well just to confirm that the `button_to` was generating the appropriate code:

```
<form action="inventories/2037/decline" method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit="return window.confirm(&quot;You are submitting information to an external page.\nAre you sure?&quot;);"><div><input style="background-color:gray;width:40px;display:inline" type="submit" value="NO"></div></form>
  <div>
    <input style="background-color:gray;width:40px;display:inline" type="submit" value="NO">
  </div>
</form>
```

In my mailer settings, I set the host properly to my domain name, so when I get the email and click the button, I get taken to `/inventories/2037/decline` appropriately, but I still get the error, because apparently the logs say I'm still trying to go for GET... why is that??

```
2014-08-17T06:18:03.206205+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/inventories/2037/decline"):
```

Comment: Can you post logs? and btw instead of hard coding your link you can use lender_accept_url(borrow)

Comment: Log says `Started GET "/inventories/2008/accept"` and then stops after that. Good point, I updated to `lender_accept_url`

Comment: if you are not able to use patch then you can change your url to use post which i'm sure will work

Comment: but the problem is i don't want to create anything new, just update the status of the record that already exists, by the way just edited question to reflect this evolution

Comment: you can use post to update your record

Comment: OH i didn't know that. So does that mean I can just have one set of routes POST that replaces the PATCH and GET? That would be great!

Comment: @Mandeep so this isn't quite working for me, when I click the link I still get an error that says `no route matches [GET]`. How do I specify in the `link_to` in the email that it should be a POST command? `method: :post` isn't working, per what dmtri.com said below

Comment: You'll have to use form for it...checkout http://superuser.com/questions/382411/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-http-post-from-a-html-email

Comment: use [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) which will generate html you are looking for

Comment: ah OK will try that approach

Comment: @Mandeep, I've updated the question would you mind taking another look? For some reason, I have a form but it's still trying to do a GET...

Comment: @Mandeep that didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Wondering if there's a better way of doing this?

Making `GET` request is ideal solution. Don't use any other request. It either be not supported by email client and potentially add big security hole.

It is your misconception that big websites use `post/patch` requests to perform such action in email. They all use `get` requests, they include some token which is tied up/trigger that particular action when user visits there website.

> OK tried the button_to to generate a form to POST to avoid using GET to do POST as was the "patchy" solution above, still not working.

Obviously, it won't work. There is no `rails` JavaScript file. Moreover, even if you include it it won't work either, because of `csrf-token` token. External form submission is not allowed by default in rails application.

My suggestion is to send user to your `dashboard` with some extra parameters `like www.example.com/dashboard?take_action=accept` and use JavaScript to trigger the required action. This will is best practice. This will avoid you using `lender_accept` request as `get`.

To to more precise, **don't do this**.

```
get 'inventories/:id/accept_email', to: 'inventories#accept', as: 'lender_accept_email'
get 'inventories/:id/decline_email', to: 'inventories#decline', as: 'lender_decline_email'
```

This is bad. Since, `get` request isn't for `updating/deleting`.

Since, you want to link this `actions` into your `email`, you should put `dashboard` link with some extra parameter. Now, with JavaScript perform `accept/decline` action whenever you see those parameters which you passed to your email.

More:

- [Can I put both Get and Post URL link in an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416753/can-I-put-both-get-and-post-url-link-in-an-email)
- [Is it possible to perform a HTTP POST from a HTML email?](https://superuser.com/questions/382411/is-it-possible-to-perform-a-http-post-from-a-html-email)
- [Is it possible to send a POST request from within an Outlook email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604791/is-it-possible-to-send-a-post-request-from-within-an-outlook-email)

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding you correctly, you're suggesting to just keep the GET solution I had earlier. But that it would be slightly better practice to do the Javascript way?

Comment: updated the answer. let me know if you have any problem

Comment: Sorry, still want to clarify, because in your answer you first said: "Making GET request is ideal solution" but then later said "don't do this: <the GET routes>", what's the discrepancy? Also, are you saying that there's not a pure Rails way of doing this?

Comment: `don't do this: <the GET routes>` I mean, you should include `GET` request. I didn't said anything which `GET` request. No, this is pure `rails` way.

Comment: OK I understand, and I did some more research so now I understand why using a GET to do any kind of POSTing is bad. But if I do the javascript way, it's equally insecure right? Because then in the GET URL, I'll still have the ID and the action, so if anyone copies/ pastes that URL, the JS action will trigger and it's essentially the same thing is it not? Sorry, very new to this

Comment: thats why big website uses `token` behaviour. This explanation is beyond the scope of question/answer,but  for sure you have to apply some logic, something like which will send unique `token` to all user. And, this practice is lot better than your original/suggested approach.

Comment: ok thanks for all the info, i'm going to do some research into token behavior and try this approach out!

Comment: My research led to more questions, so I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373406/explain-the-use-of-tokens-in-transmitting-data-over-get please feel free to help me better understand further. I just want to make sure I'm doing this right, thanks!

Comment: @james i saw your question and i see you have lot of confusion. My bad i couldn't able to explain you correctly. i gonna answer you on Friday  ..(rightnow i'm dont have time) also i will create one contrived example sample app.

Comment: @james looks like one guy has answered your question and he answered it wonderfully. Hope you understood it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the link in the email will not be able to use "PATCH" method because the email doesn't have `rails.js`. (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)

I don't think embedding `rails.js` will work though because most email legit providers will probably disable javascript in emails.

You can add `get 'inventories/:id/accept', to: 'inventories#accept', as: 'lender_accept'` in your route to circumvent this problem, but if using `get` is bad practise if you are actually changing anything in database.

My easy solution would be to link the user to some page where they can accept or decline on your website rather than accept or decline from the email.

Comment: Hmm that's a good temp solution, but tons of websites allow you to do this... click a link in the email that triggers a POST, so I have to believe there's a solution somewhere. If I add the `get` route, will that interfere with the `patch`?

Comment: Can't tell you off my head if it'll interfere or not, but I think it should be fine. But do test.

Comment: Ok this worked, i removed conflict by just using different names completely. The only challenge now is whether or not I can avoid the GET and use PATCH somehow... I changed the question to reflect that, but will accept this as teh answer if no one else comes up with anything better